# Is there a way to get the usage block of optparse-aplicative parser outside the IO monad

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

`optparse-applicative` package provides very powerful tools for command-line arguments parsing. Among them is the automatic usage text generation, which is printed in case of parsing error or by `--help` option if the parser is used by `execParser` function inside the IO monad.

Is there any way to get the usage text if using `execParserPure`?

Comment: [`parserHelp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.16.1.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Help-Core.html#v:parserHelp) looks relevant. The result has a Show instance, and its implementation delegates to `renderPretty`, which AFAICT is the canonical way to render help text (i.e., it's not a for-debugging-only Show instance).